# Why sites served with nginx have no styling applied

Tags: django, reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I try to put build of react app on localhost/ using nginx. As far as i understand this, i need to build app with "npm run build" and then serve build dir with static content. After many hours i managed to get it into work with docker and my django service as a api under localhost/api/. But what is not working is css and js on this sites. On any page neither is it react or django endpoints there is only raw html with attached css but not working. After many attempts with changing configs  etc. I ended with same raw html. Why on nginx there is no styling on sites even if with inspecting these pages there is linked css to them. 
This is my [nginx.conf](https://pastebin.com/FcUruqBN)

```
http {

  server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/html;
  server_name localhost;
         index index.html index.htm;
  location /api/ {
        proxy_pass "http://web:8000/";
}
  location / {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
        root /var/www/html;
          expires 1M;
          access_log off;
          add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }
}
}
```

This is part of [docker-compose](https://pastebin.com/nW4WiuYc)

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
    - ./nginx_conf/:/etc/nginx/
    - ./frontend/build/:/var/www/html/
    depends_on:
      - web
```

When i run this app with npm start : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ewDp.png)
When i enter localhost/ with nginx running : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8WKo.png)

Comment: I suppose, you are not serving `.css` files properly with nginx. When you running it with `npm start`, the dev-server is running, and it handles requests for local project static files by default automatically.

Comment: Yes i know that. But i can see that nginx is providing these files in console.
https://pastebin.com/PXEb5iWc

Comment: you mean, that in **Network** tab of the browser you see `200` for these files? If it's true, can you watch the content of the files - is this exactly that files, or, mb, it's just HTML?

Comment: Yes i can see in network tab css file with status 200 .

Comment: Please, check the content of the files. Or just go to the url of these files. You probably will see you webpage instead of files.

Comment: I can go there. I see builded by npm css file. copy of it here : https://pastebin.com/ytCeS5Zi

Answer (score 1):

Ok i don't understand why. But i was messing with inspector and i clicked by accident disable http cache AND bootstrap loaded!? I really have no idea how but now it works.

Comment: Well, Sh*t happens :)

Answer (score 1):

i add 2 include into server and it's worked:
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Actually only need to add one include for correct location.

In my case **nginx.conf** file looks like this.

```
events {}

http {

    server {

        listen 3000;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html index.htm;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

            expires off;
            add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
        }
    }
}
```

I add `include` inside of `location` block like this.

```
location / {
    # other configuration
    index index.html index.htm;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types; # <- This line was added

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    # other configuration
}
```

And everything worked.